# How to open closed TabItems on button click using MVVM & WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress controls. I have a DocumentLayoutManager in that I have DocumentGroup.
For Example:

```
<dxdo:DocumentLayoutManager>
<dxdo:DocumentGroup x:Name="dcGroup"/>
</dxdo:DocumentLayoutManager>
```

Also I have Buttons. For Example:

```
<Button x:Name="btn1" Command{Binding btn1Click}/>
<Button x:Name="btn2" Command{Binding btn2Click}/>
```

I'm loading Tabs in DocumentGroup from ViewModel on respective button click(Ex: btn1click = TabItem1 & btn2click = TabItem2). Now if user clicks btn1 & btn2 then both Tabs get open, now my question is if user closes any of the tabItem which is already open and then clicks on the button again then i need to show that tab in DocumentGroup again.

Comment: Can you post some code for how you are opening the Tabs in the first place?

Comment: Why can't you just open it the way you did the first time? If there is a reason why you can't do that, then fix *that* reason, because this is what you should be aiming for.

Comment: Ok good. Thanks for updating... I'll add an answer, so that this [question can be set as answered](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), as is customary on this website.

Comment: @user3336672 can you post the code of yout viewmodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when programming, we try to make repeatable functions. You said:

> Now if user clicks btn1 & btn2 then both Tabs get open, now my question is if user closes any of the tabItem which is already open and then clicks on the button again then i need to show that tab in DocumentGroup again

Your function that opens the `TabItem`s should also be repeatable. I'm guessing that you have some sort of method that you called to get and/or set the data, and generally add the `TabItem`. If the user closes a `TabItem` and then wants to reopen it, you should aim to call the same method again. If there is a particular problem or reason why you can't do that, then fix *that* problem, because this scenario is what you should be aiming for.